# How to access Child with ref in Parent's children - React@latest

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-props, ref

This code example is minimal representation of what the structure is

Main component where we group all other components:

```
<Form>
   <FormGroup>
       <RadioGroup>
           <RadioButton/>
           <RadioButton/>     
       </RadioGroup>
   </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup>
       <TextInput />
   </FormGroup>
   <Button>Submit Form</Button>
</Form>
```

The goal is to create a **reference** to every `TextInput` in the `FormGroup` or to every `RadioButton` in `RadioGroup` or even `FormGroup`, so lets go further down the components, for now Form and FormGroup are empty components rendering children:

```
const Form: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <form>
          {children}
      </form>
  );
};
```

```
const FormGroup: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }) => {

  // WE WANT TO ACCESS REF HERE, with React.Children.map every child's ref is always null

  return (
     {children}
  );
};
```

To keep it simple the `RadioGroup` also just rendering children

```
const RadioGroup: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }) => {

  // WE WANT TO ACCESS REF HERE, with React.Children.map every child's ref is always null

  return (
     {children}
  );
};
```

And we are getting to the main point, the Child we want to create a reference to, in this example the `RadioButton` component

```
class RadioButton extends Component<{props}, state> {
  this.state = {
      inputRef: React.createRef()
  };

  handleClick() {
   WE CAN ACCESS THE REF HERE
   // this.state.inputRef.current
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> // putting the ref here also doesnt work in parent components
         <label>
           <input 
               ref={this.state.inputRef} 
               onChange={() => this.handleClick()}
           />
         </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use react-hook-form if you are working with form.
[react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/)